# C# Getting from dynamic object to SQL Insert statement using SqlKata (or alternatively just ADO.NET)

Tags: c#, sql, json, dynamic, sqlkata

Please bear with me here, I've been working for hours and feel like I've started to get tired, make mistakes, and not see what I'm supposed to be seeing. If this is a stupid question I apologise. I have a loop of dynamic objects. These dynamic objects can be of varying shape, and will ultimately be inserted into a database table that matches the column names of the properties of the dynamic object. So if the object has 'Title=Mr' there will be a database column called 'Title' in the database.

I have the below loop, where I was attempting to somehow convert my dynamic object into an array of column names and an array of values, then somehow use those in my Insert statement to SQL Server using SqlKata (I'm open to a solution in plain old ADO.NET).

However, it's severely broken, and I think stress is making me not see a simpler solution to turning a dynamic object like this:

```
{
    "TRS_KEY": 712134,
    "TRS_PTR": 16974,
    "TailFlags": 0,
    "RRP": 49.95,
    "PriceType": 1,
    "PromoID": 194814003
}
```

Into an insert statement like this (assuming I have the table variable somewhere else ready to go)

```
INSERT INTO <TABLE> (TRS_KEY,TRS_PTR,TailFlags,RRP,PriceType,PromoId) VALUES(712134,16974... and so on
```

I got to the below, but it's completely messed up. I'm obviously way off here.

```
            foreach (dynamic d in r.Data)
            {
                try
                {
                    context.Logger.LogLine($"Original dynamic object serialised to JSON -> {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d)}");

                    JObject o = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d));
                    var result = o.Descendants()
                                .OfType<JProperty>()
                                .Select(p => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(p.Path,
                                p.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array || p.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object
                                ? null : p.Value));

                    var columns = result.Select(pairs => result.Select(pair => pair.Key).ToArray().ToString());
                    context.Logger.LogLine($"COLUMNS {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(columns)}");
                    var values = result.Select(pairs => result.Select(pair => pair.Value).ToArray());
                    context.Logger.LogLine($"VALUES TO GO INTO INSERTS {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values)}");

                    var queryResult = db.Query(r.TableRef).Insert(columns, values);
                    db.Logger = compiled => {
                        context.Logger.Log($"{compiled.ToString()}");
                    };

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    context.Logger.LogLine($"{ex.ToString()}");
                }
            }
```

Which products the following mess :/

[image]

I don't normally appeal to the 'emotional' side of SO, but if anyone could help out and reserve judgement at the moment, I'd appreciate it. I've only got this weekend to get this concept up and running, and I think I'm starting to feel like I can't escape my own head long enough to simply and cleanly solve this issue.

Edit - tried the answer below, but now getting this issue:

```
            foreach (dynamic d in r.Data)
            {
                //context.Logger.LogLine($"{d.GetType()}");
                try
                {
                    context.Logger.LogLine($"{r.TableRef} {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d)}");

                    JObject o = d;
                    var result = o.Descendants()
                                .OfType<JProperty>()
                                .Select(p => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(p.Path,
                                p.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array || p.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object
                                ? null : p.Value));

                    IEnumerable<string> columns = result.Select(p => p.Key);
                    IEnumerable<object> values = result.Select(p => p.Value);


                    var queryResult = db.Query(r.TableRef).Insert(columns, values);
```

Error: (red squiggly under values in Insert(columns, values) )

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 3: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>>'    S2CProcessDataStateMachine  C:\Users\jmatson\source\repos\S2CProcessDataStateMachine\S2CProcessDataStateMachine\StepFunctionTasks.cs    113 Active
```

EDIT:

Changed to

```
                    JObject o = d;
                    var result = o.Descendants()
                                .OfType<JProperty>()
                                .Select(p => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(p.Path,
                                p.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array || p.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object
                                ? null : p.Value));

                    IEnumerable<string> columns = result.Select(p => p.Key);
                    IEnumerable<object> values = result.Select(p => p.Value);

                    // Add custom columns
                    IEnumerable<string> colAdded = columns.Add("STORE_ID").Add("last_modified");

                    IEnumerable<object> valAdded = values.Add(state.StoreId).Add(DateTime.Now);


                    var queryResult = db.Query(r.TableRef).AsInsert(colAdded, valAdded );
                    queryResult.Get();
```

THis causes no errors until the SQL insert is attempted. As you can see above I add a couple of additional columns and values before inserting. All columns show up in the insert statement fine, but note only the two values I add manually appear? The rest are empty? :(

> INSERT INTO [TLog010000ItemSale] ([TRS_KEY], [TRS_PTR], [PLUID],
>   [Ext11], [Subtract], [Cancel], [Negative], [FuelItemCancel],
>   [StaffDiscAllow], [PriceOveride], [OnSale], [WSPriceOverride],
>   [ManPrice], [ManPriceAllw], [NoManWgnt], [WgtItem], [DecItem],
>   [Gallons], [ChainPrv], [NonMerch], [StoreCpn], [VendorCpn], [DiscAlw],
>   [Scan], [ReadSrv], [NextInfo], [ReplUnknown], [GSTExclFollow],
>   [PriceGrid], [DepID], [MSU], [RetnID], [TaxF], [QTY], [Price],
>   [Amount], [ExclPrice], [ExclAmount], [CaseQty], [TailFlags],
>   [NoStockDeduct], [NoLoyaltyPoints], [STORE_ID], [last_modified])
>   VALUES (, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
>   , , , , , , , , , , , 'A854', '2019-08-03 12:11:10')

Comment: What is d at runtime? Is it a string containing what you've shown, or an anonymous type?

Comment: d is this - {
    "TRS_KEY": 712134,
    "TRS_PTR": 16974,
    "TailFlags": 0,
    "RRP": 49.95,
    "PriceType": 1,
    "PromoID": 194814003
}  (It may be another JSON object, but always in the JSON format of {"thing":"value})

Comment: That is not valid C#, it's a stringification of a JSON object. What is the C# type of d? What do you get if you log `d.GetType()`?

Comment: Apologies, it's Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

Comment: OK thanks. I don't understand why you are serializing then parsing to turn it  back into a JObject. Next step, what is the type of `result`?

Comment: Also you say "can be any shape". Is it just ` {"thing":"value"}` or can value be an array? If so, I don't see how you will use this approach to turn it into SQL.

Comment: result is IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,object>> but I would ignore that, I am sure I'm over complicating it. There must be an easier way to do what I want. Ignore me serializing then parsing back to JObject. If you read my original post, I've been trying things for hours so some of the code may be redundant. 'd' or the dynamic, will always be a Json object, never an array. There is an outer loop that - if it is an array to begin with - splits it out into single objects, which is where i want to convert to a sql insert statement. To answer your question, value will never be an array.

Comment: OK, cool. Then there's no need for the nested linq `Select`, that's what's producing the complicated nested object. You just need `var columns = result.Select(pairs => pairs.Key);` which will give you an `IEnumerable<string>` containing the column names.

Comment: Thank you - so if that gives me column names, how do I progress from that, to having both columns and values suitable to build a string like INSERT INTO <TABLE> (column, column, column) VALUES (value, value, value)?

Comment: I think you basically have it already: `var queryResult = db.Query("tablename").Insert(columns, values);` should do the job, if I'm reading the docs correctly :-)

Comment: Clearly, you pull the values from `result` in the same way with a single `.Select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `result` is of type `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,object>>` the linq to get to the lists of columns and values is a simple linq `Select`. You may have nulls in the Key of the `KeyValuePair` so remove those first:

```
result = result.Where(x => x.Key != null);      
IEnumerable<string> columns = result.Select(p => p.Key);
IEnumerable<object> values = result.Select(p => p.Value);
```

This is a case where using `var` is more a hinderance than a help. If the `columns` and `values` had been declared as the type they are expected to be, the compiler would show immediately whether that matches whatever is produced by the linq query.

SqlKata function `Insert` is for a multiple insert, so expects a set of insertion value lists:

```
var queryResult = db.Query(r.TableRef).Insert(columns, new[]{values});
```

Comment: Updated my question with this attempt. Close, but still failing now with a different error. The columns and values look right to me, but fail when constructing the SqlKata insert (see edit)

Comment: OK, I see I misread the documentation, `Insert` is for a multiple insert and expects an array of arrays of values. I'll update the answer.

Comment: That stopped the error which is great, and the columns part works fine, but the values part is showing in the SQL INSERT as VALUES (, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,) (so nothing is being added)...

Comment: if I iterate through foreach (var v in valAdded) I can serialise the object to JSON and see the value of each field. I don't know why it's blank in the insert statement....

Comment: I suggest you mark my answer as accepted as it sorted out the original question, then open a new question about the SqlKata Insert with a minimal example with just the two collections and the insert. You will get a specific answer that way.